# Django 1.6: UnboundLocalError in forms

Tags: python, django, forms, view

I'm getting this unboundLocal error that says 
local variable 'genderselect' referenced before assignment

on line  131 in view.py

```
gend = Doctor.objects.get(gender = genderselect)
```

I've the same form in two different templates

Index.html

```
<div class="signup">
          <div class="form-group">
            <form action="" method="post" >
            <select class="form-control" id="selection" name="selection">
              <option><b>Find a Doctor...</b></option>
              {% for value, text in form.selection.field.choices %}
                <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
              {% csrf_token %}
            </select>

            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="submit" id="ss-submit">Find Doctors</button>
            </span>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
```

doclisting.html

```
<select class="form-control" id="selection" name="selection">
              <option><b>Find a Doctor...</b></option>
              {% for value, text in form.selection.field.choices %}
                <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>

              <select class="form-control" id="genderdropdown" name="genderdropdown">
              <option><b>Select a Gender</b></option>
              {% for value, text in form.genderselect.field.choices %}
                <option value="{{ value }}">{{ text }}</option>
              {% endfor %}
            </select>

            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"  name="submit" id="ss-submit">Search</button>
            </span>
          </div>
          {% csrf_token %}

        </form>
```

Here is the views where I'm getting the error

```
def doclistings(request):
    d = getVariables(request)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DropdownSelectionForm(request.POST)
        print form.errors

        if form.is_valid():
            selection = form.cleaned_data['selection']
            genderselect = form.cleaned_data['genderselect']
            d['usergendselect'] = genderselect
            request.session["selection"] = request.POST['selection']

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/doclistings')
    else:
        form = DropdownSelectionForm()


    s_name = request.session.get('selection')  # Change variable name
    d['userselection'] = s_name  # Update this for new variable name
    gend = Doctor.objects.get(gender = genderselect)
    spec = Specialization.objects.get(name=s_name)  # Get spec object
    doctors = Doctor.objects.filter(specialization = spec, gender = gend).order_by('-likes')  
    d['doctors'] = doctors

    d.update({'form': form})
    return render_to_response('meddy1/doclistings.html',d)
```

I'm guessing my form is not validating. I've no idea why that's happening.

Here is the form that I'm using

```
class DropdownSelectionForm(forms.Form):
    selection = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MY_CHOICES, widget = forms.Select, required = False)
    genderselect = forms.ChoiceField(choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget= forms.Select, required = False)
```

Answer (score 2):

When `request.method == 'GET'` the variable `genderselect` is not set. Its set only when form is submitted, at that time `request.method == 'POST'`.

You may want to restructure your code to appropriately set that variable for `GET` requests as well.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
gend = Doctor.objects.get(gender = genderselect)
```

Uses the variable `genderselect`, which only exists if the request method is POST. Meaning, when loading the page normally you get the `local variable 'genderselect' referenced before assignment` - because you're using an undeclared variable (python recognizes that other part of the code defines `genderselect` and assumes you're using it before assigning it, hence the error).